# Antlr v3: Printing the subtree of a given node in a parse tree

Tags: java, antlr

I'm current working on a project and I came to the point where I need to extract all methods from a given Java source code. I need to implement it in **antlr v3** but I came to a dead-end since the api documentation doesn't clarify how can one do that. I've also searched through the official book but still with no success. Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I found that in **antlr v4**  this can be done as:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);

        ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        MethodPrinter printer = new MethodPrinter();
        walker.walk(printer, tree);
        for (String method : printer.methods)
            System.out.println(method);
    }
}
```

where `Method printer` is implemented as:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNode;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MethodPrinter extends JavaBaseListener {
    boolean inMethod;
    String currentMethod;
    ArrayList<String> methods;

    public MethodPrinter() {
        inMethod = false;
        methods = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void enterMethodDeclaration(JavaParser.MethodDeclarationContext ctx) {
        inMethod = true;
        currentMethod = "";
    }

    public void exitMethodDeclaration(JavaParser.MethodDeclarationContext ctx) {
        inMethod = false;
        methods.add(currentMethod);
    }

    public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {
        if (inMethod)
            currentMethod += node.getText() + " ";
    }
}
```

How this can be implemented in **antlr v3**?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Java source code has to be encapsulated in a class.
You can use reflection to get all the methods in a given class.

```
...
Class cl = Class.forName("com.example.test.MyClass");
// or cl = someObject.getClass();
List<Method> methods = cl.getDeclaredMethods(cl);
methods.addAll(cl.getMethods());
...
```

then you can use it a  normal java list

Comment: Thank you, but here's the situation. I forgot to mention that for now I need only the methods but later I may need any integral part of the code (for example expressions,  assignments, fields declarations etc.). If I manage to make this to work my life would be easier.

Comment: I don't know about the code itself, because it might be compiled and optimized, but regarding fields, you do have `getFields()` and `getDeclaredFields()`